# Inverting an arbitrary integral

Tags: integration, inverse

$$r(x) = \int_{x_\min}^x f(y)\, dy$$

I would like to obtain an inverse for this such that I have $x(r)$. 
Is this possible? I saw [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4600/how-to-invert-an-integral-equation) post before, however my function has a $y$ involved which makes it harder for me to understand. Any hints?

Thank you for your help !

PS. I thought that I would differentiate it with respect to $y$ to get rid of the integral. Does that even make any sense?

EDIT: 
I must have explained the problem a little better. I have a random variable $x$ defined by the p.d.f $f(x)$ and a function of the random variable $r(x)$ defined with the p.d.f $g(r)$. I would like to obtain the p.d.f $g(r)$.

My approach was to use $$g(r) = f(x(r)) * \mid \frac{dx}{dr} \mid $$
However, I am stuck at the $ \frac{dx}{dr}$ since I find the original function $r(x)$ to be defined in an abstract way.

Comment: If $f(y)\geq 0$ then $r(x)$ is increasing and the inverse function exists. Obviously, its explicit form depends on $f$, so what do you really need?

Comment: I want to calculate the inverse of r(x) and then find dx/dr.

Comment: Good idea to do the differentiation, but do it with respect to $x$:
$$r(x)=\int_{x_{min}}^{x} f(y)dy$$
$$\frac{d}{dx} r(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \int_{x_{min}}^{x} f(y)dy$$
$$\frac{dr}{dx} = f(x)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to explicitly solve this problem without knowing something about $f$. By differentiating both sides with the FTC you get

$$\frac{dr}{dx} = f(x).$$

Hence the inverse function theorem gives

$$\frac{dx}{dr}=\frac{1}{f(x(r))}.$$

But this is a nontrivial ODE, meaning that you cannot simply integrate both sides to obtain $x$.

Comment: Thanks for this. This worked for my purposes. Is there something I can read to understand this better?

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose that $r$ is invertible, and write $\chi=r^{-1}$ (as Jack d'Aurizio said, it is the case when $f$ is always positive, or always negative).

If you're looking for the derivative of $\chi$, then we simply have :
$\chi'(\rho)=\frac{1}{r'(\chi(\rho))}=\frac{1}{f(\chi(\rho))}$

With a little abuse of notation :
$$\frac{dx}{dr}=\frac{1}{f(x)}$$

Comment: Your last equality is incorrect, it should be $1/f(x)$. It's also only abuse of notation inasmuch as the right side is not explicitly a function of $r$. That is, you have $\frac{dx}{dr}=\frac{1}{f(x(r))}$, which is a nontrivial ODE (i.e. it cannot be solved simply by integration).

Comment: You're right about the last equality, I edited thanks.
For the abuse of notation, it was also for writting $x(r)$, where $r$ become a variable.